# Render a 2d array as a hierarchical html table

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a data structure like this, the order can be random

```
const table = [
  ['A', 'a', 0],
  ['A', 'a', 1],
  ['A', 'b', 0],
  ['B', 'a', 0],
  ['B', 'b', 1],
  ['B', 'b', 0],
]
```

this should be render as a hierarchical table in html like this

```
<table>
  <tr><td rowspan="3">A</td><td rowspan="2">a</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="3">B</td><td>a</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="2">b</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

I wonder what would be an effective way to solve this. Thought about converting the list into a tree and then back to a list, but I'm not sure its the best way to solve this.

Comment: So i think i finally got what you mean by *the order can be random* and corrected the code accordingly. Plase see if this works out the way you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Transform each item into an object that has a rowCount and use 0 to represent that the previous item is the same so don't display it. I don't know what view binding library you are using but in Angular, Vue or React that would be really easy to then bind to a table. If you are doing it in pure JavaScript you would have to create the DOM elements in a loop.

```js
const table = [
  ['A', 'a', 0],
  ['A', 'a', 1],
  ['A', 'b', 0],
  ['B', 'a', 0],
  ['B', 'b', 1],
  ['B', 'b', 0],
];

const rowSpan = rows =>
  rows.map((row, rowIndex) =>
    row.map((item, colIndex) => ({ data: item, rowSpan: countRows(rows, rowIndex, colIndex) }))
  );

const countRows = (rows, rowIndex, colIndex) => {
  if (rowIndex > 0 && rows[rowIndex - 1][colIndex] === rows[rowIndex][colIndex]) {
    return 0;
  }
  let count = 1;
  while (count + rowIndex < rows.length && rows[rowIndex + count][colIndex] === rows[rowIndex][colIndex]) {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
};

const tableElement = document.createElement('table');

rowSpan(table).forEach(row => {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tableElement.appendChild(tr);
  row.forEach(item => {
    if (item.rowSpan) {
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      td.rowSpan = item.rowSpan;
      td.innerHTML = item.data.toString();
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  });
});

document.body.appendChild(tableElement);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a nice question. My answer might be a little long so please bear with me.

My approach is basically handling all data manipulations at JS level and then attaching the table to DOM all at once without messing with the DOM elements throughout the logic of the operation.

The basic idea is to convert the

```
var table = [ ['A', 'a', 0]
            , ['A', 'a', 1]
            , ['A', 'b', 0]
            , ['B', 'a', 0]
            , ['B', 'b', 1]
            , ['B', 'b', 0],
            ];
```

into

```
[ [ { text: 'A', span: 3, bool: true  }
  , { text: 'a', span: 2, bool: false }
  , { text: 0,   span: 1, bool: false }
  ]
,
  [ { text: 'A', span: 0, bool: true  }
  , { text: 'a', span: 0, bool: false }
  , { text: 1,   span: 1, bool: false }
  ]
,
  [ { text: 'A', span: 0, bool: true  }
  , { text: 'b', span: 1, bool: false }
  , { text: 0,   span: 1, bool: false }
  ]
,
  [ { text: 'B', span: 3, bool: true  }
  , { text: 'a', span: 1, bool: false }
  , { text: 0,   span: 1, bool: false }
  ]
,
  [ { text: 'B', span: 0, bool: true  }
  , { text: 'b', span: 2, bool: false }
  , { text: 1,   span: 1, bool: false }
  ]
,
  [ { text: 'B', span: 0, bool: true  }
    { text: 'b', span: 0, bool: false }
    { text: 0,   span: 1, bool: false }
  ]
]
```

In order to obtain this data, I use a slightly unorthodox method at two places, which i believe should have existed in JS but... we have to make it ourselves. `Array.prototype.zipWith()` which will take a function and another array and apply the provided function to the corresponding elements of the two arrays. If the arrays are of different length then it stops when all items of the shortest one is depleted. Such as

```
[1,2,3,4].zipWith((x,y) => x + y, [5,6,7])   // [6,8,10]
[1,2,3].zipWith((x,y) => x + y, [5,4,3,2,1]) // [6,6,6]
```

This could be something like

```
[].zipWith || Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype
                                   , "zipWith"
                                   , {value: function(f,a){
                                               var l = a.length;
                                               return this.reduce((r,e,i) => i < l ? ( r.push(f(e,a[i]))
                                                                                     , r
                                                                                     )
                                                                                   : r, []);
                                             }
                                     }
                                   );
```

We can separate the following code into two `reduce`ing stages at the `return` level and study accordingly.

1. `reduce`ing stage provide the interim data.
2. `reduce`ing stage creates the DOM fragment that contains the table.

As you might have noticed my indenting is also somewhat unusual but believe me once you copy paste the code on your favourite text editor it will be much easier to read it... i hope :)

So here comes the code with a slightly different data set in order to display it's behaviour when "randomness" kicks in... if i understand OP correctly.

```js
[].zipWith || Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype
                                   , "zipWith"
                                   , {value: function(f,a){
                                               var l = a.length;
                                               return this.reduce((r,e,i) => i < l ? (r.push(f(e,a[i])),r)
                                                                                   : r, []);
                                             }
                                     }
                                   );

var table = [ ['A', 'a', 1]
            , ['A', 'a', 1]
            , ['A', 'b', 1]
            , ['B', 'b', 1]
            , ['B', 'a', 0]
            , ['B', 'b', 1]
            , ['B', 'b', 1]
            , ['B', 'b', 0]
            ];

function makeTable([r,...rs]){

  var f = new DocumentFragment(),
      t = f.appendChild(document.createElement("table")),
      z = (f,s) => f.text === s ? ( f.span += 1
                                  , f
                                  )
                                : ( f.bool = false
                                  , { text: s
                                    , span: 1
                                    , bool: false
                                    }
                                  );
  t.id ="table-with-spans";
  
  return rs.reduce( function(rs,r){
                      var b = rs[rs.length-1].zipWith((f,s) => f.text === s && f.bool, r)
                                             .some(b => b);
                      
                      return ( rs.push(b ? rs[rs.length-1].zipWith(z,r)
                                         : r.map(d => ({ text: d
                                                       , span: 1
                                                       , bool: true
                                                       })
                                                )
                                      )
                             , rs
                             )
                    }
                  , [r.map(d => ({ text: d
                                 , span: 1
                                 , bool: true
                                 })
                          )
                    ]
                  )
           .reduce( function(t,r){
                      var tds = r.filter(td => td.span),
                          tde;
                      t.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"))
                       .append(...tds.map(function(td){
                                            tde = document.createElement("td");
                                            tde.textContent = td.text;
                                            tde.rowSpan     = td.span;
                                            td.span = 0;
                                            return tde;
                                          })
                              );
                        return t;
                    }
                  , t
                  ).parentNode;
}

document.getElementById("table-container")
        .appendChild(makeTable(table));
```

```css
#table-with-spans {
  width          : 50vw;
  text-align     : center;
  border         : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing : 2px;
  margin         : 0 auto;
}

tr{
  height : 2.5vw;
}

td {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="script.js" async></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table-container">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```